# Packet loss when sending too fast on macos

Tags: c, macos, sockets

environment: macbook pro, macOS Mojave 10.14.6

I was testing the throughput of injecting packets into wireless network.

The problem is, when I send udp packets to my router for 100K times in a loop, only about 16K are actually injected into the network, but all 100K calls to 'sendto' return successfully.

```
char dbuf[1100] = "\0";
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
uint32_t ip_binary_net = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
struct sockaddr_in sa;
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(5577);
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_binary_net;

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    int send_num = sendto(sockfd, dbuf, 1000, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
    if(send_num != 1000)
        printf("send_num err!\n");
}
```

My program shows the throughput is 2G Mbps, which is absolutely impossible.

I checked the Network Utility, wireshark on my macbook and the router. Cleary only small part of those packets were actually injected into the network.

I met the same problem using libpcap.
But this problem did not happen on my windows machine.
Is this some feature of the macOS kernel?

Comment: How do you know they return successfully?

Comment: the return value of 'sendto' is 1000

Comment: Just an idea for better analysis: Put an index in every packet and look at the receiving end which ones are missing.

Comment: I indexed every packet.  The first packet loss happened at No.882, the next packet captured by wireshark is No.1198. This situation happened every few hundred packets. I guess the kernel's buffer may be the reason, but I'm not sure。

Comment: What do you think UDP is supposed to do?

Comment: I capture the packet on my local macbook using wireshark, the same problem occurred when I use libpcap to send raw link frame. The problem is those packets were NOT actually sent by the kernel, which has nothing to do with the network. And this problem only appears on macOS

Comment: Is it possible that you fill up some kind of buffer in the OS network stack which simply discards the packages rather than blocking until sent? I mean, udp is fire-and-forget, after all?